# 'where' clause at the end of all join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Assuming that i have 2 sql query as below, will the query result ever be difference?

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.IsActive = 1
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID
WHERE C.IsActive = 1

SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID
WHERE B.IsActive = 1 AND C.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: Your first query is syntactically incorrect. In your second query you've used `Active` column name in place of `IsActive`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first query is syntactically incorrect. It needs to be rewritten:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.IsActive = 1
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID
WHERE C.IsActive = 1
```

Now after correction, if I compare below two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.IsActive = 1
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID AND C.IsActive = 1
```

Estimated execution plan:

[image]

**Vs**

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID
WHERE B.IsActive = 1 AND C.IsActive = 1
```

Estimated execution plan:

[image]

Then, they are exactly the same:

- In terms of final output/result
- In terms of performance and query execution plan

**Note**: There is no advantage of using one syntax over the other. It is all about personal preference which is convenient to you and your team. SQL Server's execution engine does the work for you to create same execution plan irrespective of the way you write your query.

Comment: I see. Is there any advantage of using one over another?

Comment: I would write the query in the first way. It creates relatively smaller result set which has to be joined with third table. I've updated my post to reflect thought.

Comment: Your *Advantage* is absolutely wrong..  Both with have identical execution plan. Optimizer is smart enough to handle this.

Comment: @desmondlee - Both will not have any performance difference. I prefer to use the second type. Keep the Join predicates in `ON` clause and filters in `Where` clause

Comment: @Pரதீப் I had that apprehension. I went ahead and checked the same to verify your feedback. I've updated my post. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and helping me correct my post.

Comment: Thats more like it ;) +1